# jenkins restart with wrong port after plugin install

Tags: jenkins

I am running jenkins on winstone with java wrapper.

In my wrapper.conf, we have set 8070 as the http port that our jenkins instance listens to.

When starting or restarting my jenkins instance manually from command line, e.g. `rc.d start jenkins`, everything works as expected and my instance is launched and bound to the 8070 port.

However, after I have installed a jenkins plugin and selected the "go into automatic restart after plugin install", my jenkins instance gets started up on **port 32000**.  I am not sure why this happens and everytime this happens, I have to - in command line - manually stop my jenkins instance and start it again.

Is there a configuration that I need to set to ensure that my jenkins - when restarted from its interface - uses the java wrapper service (which contains the correct port - 8070)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not suggested to use the auto restart when Jenkins starts with the Java wrapper service. 
The auto restart supposes that Jenkins was started manually and can't restart it with a service.

Comment: So what is the alternative? How can I configure  the auto restart start up in a specific way? Is there an API or hook to Jenkins which allows me to specify a custom restart method?

Answer (score 0):

The port 32000 is used by the wrapper itself. It is not the jenkins's http port.
I had the same problem with automatic restart and java service wrapper.
I don't know why "It's not suggested to use the auto restart when Jenkins starts with the Java wrapper service."? I never read anything about it!
Sure it doesn't listen on the 8070 port after the auto restart (tested with netstat).